# How to set TitleBar Icon in UWP?

Tags: c#, uwp, titlebar, uwp-xaml

How to set up icon to TitleBar(Window) in UWP?

Example of TitleBar Icon:
[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We can customize title bar to set up TitleBar Icon. The key point here is using [Window.SetTitleBar method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.window.settitlebar.aspx). Following is a simple sample:

Firstly, we need a [UIElement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.aspx) as the new title bar. For example, in *MainPage.xaml* we can add a `Grid` and in the grid, set the icon and application name. Please note that we need put the "TitleBar" `Grid` in the first row of the root grid.

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid x:Name="TitleBar">
        <Rectangle x:Name="BackgroundElement" Fill="Transparent" />
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Image Height="32" Margin="5,0" Source="Assets/StoreLogo.png" />
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="My Application" />
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Then in *MainPage.xaml.cs*, we can use following code to set the new title bar with icon.

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();

    CoreApplication.GetCurrentView().TitleBar.ExtendViewIntoTitleBar = true;
    // Set the BackgroundElement instead of the entire Titlebar grid
    // so that we can add clickable element in title bar.
    Window.Current.SetTitleBar(BackgroundElement);
}
```

For more info, you can refer to the official [Title bar sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/TitleBar) on GitHub, especially scenario 2: **Custom drawing** in the sample.