# React Native Windows UWP missing window icon in upper-left corner

Tags: react-native, visual-studio, uwp, icons, react-native-windows

I've got a react native for windows app and I've used Visual Studio's Asset Generator to generate my application's icons. That worked great, and it has set the start menu icon, taskbar icon, search icon, etc. But my application does not have an icon in the upper left corner of the window like all other windows apps.

Visual studio: [image]

Sublime Text: [image]

Mine: [image]

How do I set this icon? Is there an option in Visual Studio somewhere?
Some instructions for a UWP app are here: [How to set TitleBar Icon in UWP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38340721/how-to-set-titlebar-icon-in-uwp)
But I can't figure out how to do this with react native.
Thanks!